# Read files from multiple folders from ADLS gen2 storage via databricks and create single target file

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I'm using databricks service for analysis. I have built a connection with ADLS gen2 storage and create a mountpoint and now that container contains multiple folder for years and months  and having parquet files for each month inside month folders. I have to read all those files and create a single target file with complete months data. How do I achieve it can anyone suggest?

Comment: is the data partitioned - your directories have names like `col=value`, or just directories?

Comment: Just directories

Comment: Can you share the file type, schema of the files, and what the schema of the final output would be as well?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your parquet files follow a specific directory pattern, you can [use wildcards](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#external-datasets).

If your files are written in a pattern like `/mnt/point/folder/YYYY/MM/foo.parquet` you can traverse all YYYY and MM folders and files with `/mnt/point/folder/*/*`

Here's a reproducible pyspark example assuming you have a mount point called 'data`.

```py
df_A = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['a',1],
    ['a',2],
    ['a',3]
], ["Letter", "Number"])
df_B = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['b',1],
    ['b',2],
    ['b',3]
], ["Letter", "Number"])

df_A.write.parquet('/mnt/data/mydata/1999/01')
df_B.write.parquet('/mnt/data/mydata/2001/09')

new_df = spark.read.parquet('/mnt/data/mydata/*/*')
```

Per @Alex Ott's comment, if your data were partitioned (e.g. had a folder named year=1999 and subfolders named month=01, month=02, etc.) you could take advantage of [partition discovery](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery) and spark would more intelligently realize that it should traverse all sub-folders.